Is there an idiomatic way to prove ownership of a (extended) public key?
Is there an idiomatic way to verify ownership of an (extended) public key? Preferably without spending coins, although I'm also interested in methods of doing so by producing a transaction as this seems more straightforward.
To give some context, a person might publicly announce an (extended) public key for other people to include in descriptor multisigs. It would provide some peace of mind for everyone involved that the keys are provably in possession by everyone who claims to own them.

Does this answer your question? How does "Sign Message" work?

It answers half of it :) How can I use such a message to verify that the signer used a specific (child key of an extended) public key.
